# How do I crawl an infinite-scrolling page?

Tags: javascript, ruby, web-crawler

I'm trying to build something that crawls the content from a page with infinite scroll. However, I can't get the stuff from below the first 'break'. How do I do this?

Comment: We'll have to know how the infinite scrolling is implemented in order to answer your question. It is probably done using AJAX calls. This means that if your crawler is written in a server side language like ruby, you'll need a wqy to execute te javascript on that page.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Infinite scrolling is almost always done in JavaScript by using AJAX, or related technology.  As such, it is not enough for your web crawler to get the HTML and parse it; it must download and execute the javascript, or at least scan it for the AJAX calls.

Doing a full javascript execution is probably *best* (ie, will be most guaranteed to work), but is probably the hardest to do.

Scanning the javascript for AJAX requests and/or looking for functions that execute AJAX calls and then do DOM manipulation will probably be easiest (relative to full JS execution)

Comment: Thanks. Since I'm a relative newb, can you give me an example of how to do that?

Comment: This is not a simple thing to do.  But however you have written your crawler to receive the HTML and parse it, have it look for `script` tags, get the url from the `src` attribute, then download the JS and scan for `xmlhttp` and what-not.

Comment: And even scanning for xmlhttp could get complicated, as it is probably called by another function. So let's ay you find a call of xmlhttp, that is used by $.ajax, now you have to go back to the place where $.ajax is called, which could be a different function defined by the user. In short, you'd have to traverse the entire call stack to find out the url of the resource that is being downloaded, but there's more trouble, the url coud be constructed dynamically. To solve this problem, google relies on webmasters adding specific markup to allow crawling of ajax pages,

Comment: take a look on this link for more info on google's way of crawling such pages: take a look here: https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/

Answer (score 3):

This answer should be relevant for a large percentage of infinite scrollers, obviously your milage might vary.

Most infinite scrollers work by using an offset position and just grab the next chunk of items from the offset. It's exactly the same as how paging might work by stepping through

`< Previous 1 2 3 4 5 Next >` except that the offsets are stored and used to make a fresh request.

With this in mind, if you open up the developer toolbar in Chrome or Firefox and check out the network tab, you will most likely see requests coming in as you scroll down.

Look at the parameters on the request, and you will most likely see something like

```
GET /api/v2/books?offset=100=count=10
GET /api/v2/books?offset=110=count=10
GET /api/v2/books?offset=120=count=10
```

Knowing this, you can very easily ignore actually scraping of the target HTML, and just use their internal target URI to make your requests.

Answer (score 0):

An ajax request is no different from any other request. You simply make the request, parse the result, and there you have your data.

It can take some experience if you haven't done it before but it sounds like a good learning experience.